# Passing packages to a MPI cluster in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a simulation using an MPI cluster.  It works well when I do not need extra packages.  For example, I can get a liner model coefficients with multiple datasets running parallel.  But when I try to do the same with quantile regression, I need to use the 'quantreg' package.  So I use the following code.  But the system quits by saying "there is no package called 'quantreg'.  But all of the nodes have it.  My admin took take of it.  I tried using the .package='quantreg', but keep getting the same error.  I really appreciate if someone can suggest some solution.  I also tried clusterApply and clusterCall with no success.

```
library("Rmpi")
library("doMPI")

mycluster <- startMPIcluster(count=12)
registerDoMPI(mycluster)


# Using parallel; you can check it with the nodename info


trials<-50

output <- foreach(a=c(.3,.5,.7), .combine = data.frame) %dopar% {

  foreach( b=icount(trials) , .combine = data.frame) %dopar% {

    set.seed(b)
    x=matrix(runif(500),100,5)
    y=rnorm(100)
    betas<-quantreg::rq(y ~ x, tau = a)$coef
    result <- c(betas, Sys.info()[c ("nodename")])

  }
}
```

The PBS script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N AYParallel
#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=8
#PBS -l walltime=00:05:00
#PBS -q una
# #PBS -j oe


module load R
module load mpi/mvapich2-x86_64
module load openmpi/3.0.0  

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1


mpirun -np 1 R --file=test0.R
```

Comment: Look into https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/nested.pdf for nested `foreach()` loops.

Comment: Try to provide a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example (can you reproduce the error without nested loop? without PBS?, etc...)

Comment: Thanks, Florian.  Let me play with the nested `foreach()` code.  Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: Florian was right!!  Thanks, Florian!  Once I used the correct nested loop structure as explained in the first link by Florian it worked.  Thanks again Florian.  We can close this thread as resolved, I'm not sure how to do it.